# Apache status "150 requests currently being processed, 0 idle workers"

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, web-server, ubuntu-16.04, mod-reqtimeout

My Apache Server Scoreboard Status is as shown below when the "150 requests currently being processed, 0 idle workers" condition is hit.

--Log-trace---

Apache Server Status for localhost (via 127.0.0.1)

Server Version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g
Server MPM: worker
Server Built: 2020-08-12T21:35:50
__________________________________________________________________

Parent Server Config. Generation: 3
Parent Server MPM Generation: 2
Server uptime: 1 day 9 hours 19 minutes 58 seconds
Server load: 0.85 0.93 1.04
Total accesses: 931102 - Total Traffic: 17.8 GB
CPU Usage: u3289.89 s950.31 cu0 cs0 - 3.53% CPU load
7.76 requests/sec - 155.9 kB/second - 20.1 kB/request
150 requests currently being processed, 0 idle workers

RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRWRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR

--Log trace-end--

Question) We use the Apache MPM module and below are the worker settings.

File: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/worker.conf

ServerLimit         25
  StartServers        2
  ThreadLimit         64
  MaxClients          150
  MinSpareThreads     25
  MaxSpareThreads     75
  ThreadsPerChild     25
  MaxRequestsPerChild 0
  ListenBacklog       511

We observed MaxClients is full (150) and this is a matter of concern and trying to find why MaxClient is becoming 150 on ad-hoc basis.

I verified the Application log (bitbucket) and no issue found in Java Application.

Now the question is how to debug this / find the Root cause , why the threads are in "Reading Request" status.

Below is the list of Loaded modules in the Ubuntu server.

Loaded Modules:
core_module (static)
so_module (static)
watchdog_module (static)
http_module (static)
log_config_module (static)
logio_module (static)
version_module (static)
unixd_module (static)
access_compat_module (shared)
alias_module (shared)
auth_basic_module (shared)
authn_core_module (shared)
authn_file_module (shared)
authz_core_module (shared)
authz_groupfile_module (shared)
authz_host_module (shared)
authz_user_module (shared)
autoindex_module (shared)
cgid_module (shared)
dav_module (shared)
dav_fs_module (shared)
deflate_module (shared)
dir_module (shared)
env_module (shared)
filter_module (shared)
headers_module (shared)
mime_module (shared)
negotiation_module (shared)
proxy_module (shared)
proxy_http_module (shared)
reqtimeout_module (shared)
rewrite_module (shared)
setenvif_module (shared)
mod_shib (shared)
socache_shmcb_module (shared)
ssl_module (shared)
status_module (shared)
mpm_worker_module (shared)

Seeking guidance in this regard to find why threads are reaching MaxClients (150) and threads are in "Reading request" status for ~ 22 Seconds.

Comment: Are you under attack?

Comment: No, it is ad-hoc or intermittent. My Grafana thread monitor shows after 1 minute the thread usage becomes normal.

Comment: Sharing my Apache KeepAlive setting of file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf as below 
KeepAlive Off 
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100 
KeepAliveTimeout 15 
Configuration of file /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/reqtimeout.conf is as below RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,minrate=500 
RequestReadTimeout body=10,minrate=500 

My server Normal thread usage will be 50 to 75.  
I observed this "Reading Request" last for ~20  seconds.

Is the KeepAlive setting are wrong in my case?
When "KeepAlive Off " then still "KeepAliveTimeout 15" will be in effect?